# Alert and keypad display is not good

Tags: android, android-intent, cordova

In my app ,i am using phonegap. I am using javascript alert .But the thing is the alert is displayed as shown in the below image.

[image]

The brown color image is the splash screen. and also there is another problem with app.
that when i open the keypad the splash screen is seen just before the keypad displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you aren't suppose to be showing an alert on a splahscreen. before you costumize your alert or switching to [navigator.notification.alert](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert) you should first cancel the timer on your splashscreen and hide it explicitly when the device is ready (onDeviceReady). Moreover, i would recommend using one of the numerous frameworks for mobile web development and using that framework's alert function, its usually better. good luck

Comment: See i am not showing the alert on splash screen . After the splash screen there is a form for validation in the app. i have used a alert to show the validation error. that error is shown as in image. Actully the splash screen comes and alert come like above.

Comment: i think it will be better if you post your code since i am having a hard time understanding your english

Comment: After splash screen, login screen of the app gets loaded. In that login screen there will be two text box. For those two text box there will be validation.If there is a error in the validation , then it will be alerted using javascript alert.Usually the alert will be shown over the login page itself right but instead it is shown as in the image given in  my question. I cannot share the code because my company logo and details of my project will be visible.

Comment: so change or blur the details needed in the relevant code, otherwise it will be extremely difficult to help you. for the very least I need to see the validation function and the code responsible for your splashscreen. I can not debug code I havent seen and if anyone can I worship him.